# Windows Ce Deploy Error

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

I have  M3 Terminal that have Windows Ce .NEt 4.02
I create a Windows Ce project with Visual Studio 2008 
I am usin SqlCe connection for connect to SqlServer When I Deploy the my project.Vs try to 
install Sql Compact Frame work rep ,SqlCompact Core then I get a error messaje from device like this setup not for this o.s.  What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on your question.  Is your target device running CE 4.0 or 4.2?  There is a (pretty large) difference.

The problem you're seeing, if I'm correct, is that when you attempt to deploy from Studio 2008, the SQL Compact CAB is unable to expand because it's set to not support OSes of that version number?  So when you deploy, it fails to continue past that point?

Assuming that's your failure, there are some things to understand.

- CE 4.x is not a "supported" target for Studio 2008.
- Managed code isn't supported on CE 4.0 at all.
- CE 4.2 supports CF 1.0 and 2.0 (though 3.5 I suspect would work)
- Studio 2008 only supports CF 2.0 and 3.5

It's quite likely that the SQL Compact CAB Studio is deploying is marked for a minimum OS version of 5.0, since that's the minimum OS version officially "supported", but if you look on your PC at

`%Program Files%\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices\wce400`

you'll see you have CABs for 4.x.  Manually install that (copy and run) which will put the registry entries on the device that say SQL Compact is installed.  That should make Studio "see" it and skip deployment.  You're probably going to hit the same issue for the Compact Framework as well if it's not already in ROM.  In that case, manually deploy the files from

`%Program Files%\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\WindowsCE\wce400`